# Jfrog artifactory intigration with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, cicd

I created a local docker repository on jfrog artifactory now, I want to push the docker image using jenkins pipeline. can some one guide me and provide some resource link as well

Answer (score 2):

You can find the complete snippet here
https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/docker-push-example/Jenkinsfile

ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REGISTRY should be `IP/Artifactory-Repo-Key/IMAGE:TAG`

HOST should be docker daemon.

Comment: Adding to this answer - the official documentation can be found here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-DockerBuildswithArtifactory

Comment: Hi 

  stage ('Artifactory configuration') {
            steps {
                rtServer (
                    id: "jfrog-artifactory",
                    url://erl-artifactory7.eso.local/ui/ ,
                    credentialsId : "evsil-import-dev-jfrog" 
            
                )
            }
        }

Comment: Error i receive on 

Started by user Hamza Nasir (ADM)
Running as Hamza Nasir (ADM)
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://bitbucket.eso.local/scm/ittool/evisl-import-dev.git
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 44: illegal colon after argument expression;
   solution: a complex label expression before a colon must be parenthesized @ line 44, column 35.
                       credentialsId : "evsil-import-dev-jfrog" 
                                     ^

Comment: The error message is not clear enough to understand it. Also your bitbucket url seems to be private. 
If the credential is having an issue, you may define the user as below by directly passing url, user name and password. 
server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'http://localhost:8082/artifactory', username: 'admin', password: 'password'
Also, it seems there is some semi colon missing at line number 44.

Comment: Dear Gajapathi 

Now the error is different 
Pushing image: hamzanasir6886/evsil-dev:latest using docker daemon host: https://erl-artifactory7.eso.local
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported protocol scheme: https://erl-artifactory7.eso.local
 at com.github.dockerjava.netty.NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.init(NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.java:112)

Answer (score 1):

Given Artifactory acts as any other docker registry, you can simply use the [Docker step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in a Pipeline and do something like the below.

```
docker.withRegistry('https://artifactoryu.registryy', 'credentials-id') {

        def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")

        /* Push the container to the custom Registry */
        customImage.push()
    }
```

Else you can simply use a shell script to do this.

```bash
sh'''
docker login ${server-name}.jfrog.io
docker tag <image name> ${server-name}.jfrog.io/{repo-name}/<image name>
docker push ${server-name}.jfrog.io/{repo-name}/<image name>
'''
```